# LevelHelper and Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Why do I get a black screen when I generate Lua code from the newest version (1.4.7) of LevelHelper My Old Level files work with my code and it generated only one lua file. The new one generates a set of 10-12 files, and leaves me with a black screen on the Corona simulator.

- Am I doing anything drastically wrong?
- Has the use of Level Helper changed with the new version?
- All the tutorials and blogs I checked are showing the use of the old LevelHelper. any repositories / github links you would like to point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everybody else who has this problem, your config.lua file must look something like this

```
application = 
{
content = 
{ 
    fps = 60,
    width = 320,
    height = 480, 
    scale = "letterbox",        
    imageSuffix =
    {
        ["-hd"] = 2
    }
},

LevelHelperSettings = 
{
    imagesSubfolder = "Images",
    levelsSubfolder = "Levels",
    directorGroup = nil
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this?

http://www.levelhelper.org/?page_id=1596

And also the latest tutorial for Corona SDK that talk LevelHelper 1.4

http://www.levelhelper.org/?p=1821

While the old LevelHelper was generating only one lua file - the new one generated multiple files because it added many complex features that could not be encapsulated in only one lua file.

Also, i want to stress that if you want fast response you should mail me or write to the LevelHelper forum.

I can help you out with your code and what you're doing wrong if you show me how you load the level.

Since you probably load it as the old way you should read the Getting Started chapter in the API Documentation.

You are probably missing the config.lua settings.

Comment: We are playing with the Jet Joyride code also. When we use the resources supplied to us, it works! and when we just replace your resources and overwrite them with our generated resources, we are left with a black screen.

And yes, I'll mail your directly over your website next time around.